# How to migrate existing .net web site and sql server 2005 database to azure platform

Tags: database, azure, using, migrate

HI,
I want to migrate the existing application using sql server 2005 database to windows azure and sql azure.
We has access to the Azure developer portals: Windows Azure ,Microsoft SQL Azure  and  AppFabric 
Is there any documentation to help the migration of existing web application to windows azure and migration of the sql server 2005 database to sql azure and integrating them.

Regards,
Pravin

Comment: 1. Search in SO.. We have many related questions 2. Did you search the web? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If your app is "just" managed code and SQL 2005, then the migration can be quite straightforward.

There are a few "gotcha's" in SQL (a few missing items from SQL Azure) but overall 80% of the move can be quite pleasant :)

These's quite a lot of information available on migration from Microsoft - articles like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff872379.aspx

I'd recommend you start with just a few "Hello World" experiments to get familiar with the tools, then try moving bits of your platform across.